# *ngFor is displaying only 1000 records in angular 4

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am using ngFor to display data in the view, but it is displaying only 1000 records, I am getting more than 1000 records from Api, even in the .ts file, i used console, I am getting proper data, but only in the grid I am getting 1000 records.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item  of mf.data | orderBy: {property: column, direction: direction } ; let ndx = index" class="InnerFormCenterLabel">

                                    <td>{{item.ROWNUM}}</td>
                                    <td><a style="color: blue;text-decoration: underline;cursor:pointer" (click)="openReportDeal(item)">{{item.CONT_SUB_MATTER }}</a></td>
                                    <td>{{item.BuNo.}}</td>
                                    <td>{{item.Contract}}</td>


                                </tr>
```

Comment: Some code, stackblitz, demo please ..

Comment: Hi i checked demo on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e1f9hq which is provided by ng2-pagination and its working file with more then 1000 records.

Comment: I have removed that control and checked, still I am facing same issue, may be some issue with ngFor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <table class="table tableheight table-responsive  table-striped table-bordered" [mfData]="data" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="10000">
```

[mfRowsOnPage] by default value is 1000. After explicit mentioned that variable [mfRowsOnPage] and after assigning some required value, it is worked fine.